# How to use SQLITE -D_SQLITE_USER_AUTHENTICATION

Tags: authentication, sqlite

I have downloaded the SQLITE amalgamation folder along with the entire source code.

Followed the steps mentioned here http://www.sqlite.org/src/doc/trunk/ext/userauth/user-auth.txt

Using the following command to build the sqlite3.exe

cl -D_SQLITE_USER_AUTHENTICATION shell.c sqlite3.c userauth.c -Fesqlite3.exe

But i can still open the database with sqlite3_open_v2. No authentication is required.

Comment: Did you try reading or writing to the database after opening it? You need a database object to pass to `sqlite3_user_authenticate`, so open must succeed.

Comment: Yes. I did not require the sqlite3_user_authenticate method. Straight away sqlite3_open_v2 and was able to exec all the commands. 
The documentation says that sqlite_user table will become active once you compile it with D_SQLITE_USER_AUTHENTICATION. I couldn't see that either.

Comment: It also says "By default a database does not require authentication." You need to add the admin user with `sqlite3_user_add` to convert it to a DB that needs authentication. (Also, as a warning, this extension doesn't seem to provide encryption, so the database is still readable to anyone who has the file)

Comment: I should add it through the program or is there a way to do from the command line itself?

Answer (score 2):

Steps I followed to add User authentication

1. Download the amalgamation and the src folder.

//Steps 2 and 3 cause i wanted just 1 source and header file.

2. Copy userauth.c code to sqlite3.c
3. Copy sqlite3userauth.h to sqlite3.h
4. cl -DSQLITE_USER_AUTHENTICATION shell.c sqlite3.c -Fesqlite3.exe
5. Now open the above executable(sqlite3.exe)
6. Write the following commands
   `.open Test.db`
   `PRAGMA writable_schema = 1`
   `.user add User User123 1` //.user add Username Password IsAdmin
7. Exit and open the db once again. It will need an authentication